# How to open a mat file in python

Tags: python

I was trying to open a mat file in python but my attempts did fail.
Here is my code

```
from  scipy import *
from  pylab import *


save('rfdata.mat')
import scipy.io as sio
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('rfdata.mat');
```

python says that :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ali\.spyder2-py3\template.py", line 14, in <module>
    mat = scipy.io.loadmat('rfdata.mat');
NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined
```

EDIT: I removed all code above and wrote

```
import scipy.io as sio
mat = sio.io.loadmat('rfdata.mat');
```

still does not work

I appreciate your help

Thanks

Comment: you have to install `scypi` module (use `pip install scypi` with an internet connection)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: You may want to check your spelling on scipy and make your comment in to the accepted answer. But apart from that I think you're absolutely right.

Comment: @JonasByström actually no: the import is under another name. Didn't see it, I never import as another name as I find it misleading.

Comment: thanks but it still does not work , please look at EDIT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you did:

```
import scipy.io as sio
```

You loaded `scipy.io` into `sio`. So, when you call:

```
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('rfdata.mat');
```

`scipy` is not defined, but `sio` is:

```
mat = sio.loadmat('rfdata.mat')
```

Moreover:

- try to place all imports at the begining of the file;
- do not use `;` at the end of a line, it is not needed in Python.

Comment: thanks ,, I did it now but python says : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ali\.spyder2-py3\template.py", line 11, in <module>
    save('rfdata.mat')
TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arr'`

Comment: See the documentation to see how to use [scipy's save function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html). `arr` is a positional argument pointing to the data to save into *rfdata.mat*.

Comment: If this solution is correct, could you accept the answer please?